# Triggering a Javascript/jQuery on next page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am writing an in house jobs management workflow and want to trigger a JavaScript function when I redirect the user to a new page after filling in a form.

Currently I am echoing the following to the page upon a successful MySQL insert, and then using PHP to present a success message to the user, however I would like to change this to JavaScript/jQuery to make the pages a little more beautiful

```
<body onLoad="window.location=index.php?success=' . $Message .'"></body>
```

I am not sure if this is possible, but I thought I would ask the question as I am a novice with jQuery/Javascript.

Comment: That seems like a complicated way of doing something very simple. Why don't you direct the user to the correct page when submitting the form and use PHP to display the message? Best of both worlds and the page doesn't break with JS disabled.

Comment: Thanks @Juhana that is what i am currently doing.  When the form submits, it runs the mysql insert/updates as required and when complete redirects to the page as described above.  I was hopeful that i could change this so i can use a javascript notification like Gritter http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, You can display an alert on DOMContentLoaded like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('Operation Success!');
});
```

`DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when HTML is parsed and scripts are executed but before other resources like css/images are completely downloaded, so you can still see a spinning wheel in the window title bar.

If you want to display message only after complete load, then you can look for `load` event of window like this

```
$(window).load(function() {
      alert('Operation Success!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Arkantos, is there a way of triggering this from the previous 'referring' page?

Comment: if you want to show that message within the same page after your sql insert, then I suggest you do an Ajax call, so that you'll remain in the same page, a request is sent to the server in the background without refreshing the page and then once the call is success, you can display your message :)

Comment: Guys, if you think that my answer is not relevant to the question, you can down vote it but please leave a comment as well, down votes on their own are NOT helping :)

Comment: Thanks @Arkantos.  I think your suggestion is great.  Ajax sounds like the best option, I was just hopeful I would not need to rewrite all my pages ;$  anyway, thanks for your input it was very helpful!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)